# R function returning unexpected number of vectors

Tags: r

I have written an R function which takes in a string pattern such as:

```r
"+pimple -lymphatic +blood"
```

Code is here:

```
extract_search_tokens <- function(pattern) {

    
    include_tokens = c()
    exclude_tokens = c()
    include_token = ""
    exclude_token = ""
    processing_include <- FALSE
    processing_exclude <- FALSE
    
    for (c in 1:nchar(pattern)) {

        token = substr(pattern, c, c)

        if (token == "+") {

            processing_include <- TRUE
            processing_exclude <- FALSE

            if (include_token != "") {                
                include_tokens <- append(include_tokens, include_token)
            }

            if (exclude_token != "") {               
                exclude_tokens <- append(exclude_tokens, exclude_token)
            }

            include_token = ""
            exclude_token = ""

        } else if (token == "-") {   

            processing_include <- FALSE
            processing_exclude <- TRUE

            if (include_token != "") {                
                include_tokens <- append(include_tokens, include_token)
            }

            if (exclude_token != "") {                
                exclude_tokens <- append(exclude_tokens, exclude_token)
            }

            include_token = ""
            exclude_token = ""
        }    




        if (processing_include == TRUE) {
            # while we are in this mode, we are assembling a token to include character by charachter
            include_token <- paste(include_token, token)
            print(include_token)
        }

        if (processing_exclude == TRUE) {
            # while we are in this mode, we are assembling a token to include character by charachter
            exclude_token <- paste(exclude_token, token)
            print(exclude_token)
        }

            
        if (c == nchar(pattern)) {
            # we have processed the last item, so need to store the last token we have been accumulating
            if (include_token != "") {                
                include_tokens <- append(include_tokens, include_token)
            }

            if (exclude_token != "") {               
                exclude_tokens <- append(exclude_tokens, exclude_token)
            }

        }

    }
    
    print(include_tokens)
    print(exclude_tokens)
    return(c(include=include_tokens, exclude=exclude_tokens))
}
```

it should split out the `+` and `-` tokens into separate vectors (`include_tokens` and `exclude_tokens`), and return a vector of length 2.

So with a pattern as stated above, I was expecting:

```r
include_tokens = c('+pimple', '+blood')
exclude_tokens = c('-lymphatic')
```

What I actually get back is the following:

> include1' + p i m p l e  'include2' + b l o o d'exclude' - l y m p h a t i c  '

The function is returning a vector of length 3.

Any ideas?  I suspect I should be using a list rather than a vector to return, but am interested to know what is actually happening to give me a 3-item vector, with `include1` and `include2` labels?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use `c` as your indexing variable.

Comment: changing c to letter_index gives same outcome, but good point

Comment: I'm lazy to check your code but here is another choice: `x <- "+pimple -lymphatic +blood" ; y <- strsplit(x, '\\s+')[[1]] ; split(y, substr(y, 1, 1))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai how do I then get to the + and - values separately? it returns a + vector with one item, but there are two + terms

Comment: With my code, I get a list of 2 vectors, one's name is "-" and has one item (`"-lymphatic"`), the other's name is "+" and has two items (`"+pimple"` & `"+blood"`).

Comment: @DarrenTsai thanks, you are correct.  I will never get used this [[]] syntax coming from python

Comment: @DarrenTsai I have no idea how your code is doing what its doing, lol

Answer (score 0):

The function can be designed like this:

```r
extract_search_tokens <- function(txt) {
  cut <- regmatches(txt, gregexpr('[+-]?[^ +-]+', txt))[[1]]
  label <- c('include', 'exclude', 'unknown')[match(sub('[^+-]+', '', cut), c('+', '-', ''))]
  var <- sub('^[+-]', '', cut)
  split(var, label)
}
```

It can handle the following 3 scenarios:

**Case 1:** Separated with space

```r
x1 <- "+pimple -lymphatic +blood"
extract_search_tokens(x1)

# $exclude
# [1] "lymphatic"
# 
# $include
# [1] "pimple" "blood"
```

**Case 2:** Separated without space

```r
x2 <- "+pimple-lymphatic+blood"
extract_search_tokens(x2)

# $exclude
# [1] "lymphatic"
# 
# $include
# [1] "pimple" "blood"
```

**Case 3:** Missing sign

```r
x3 <- "pimple -lymphatic +blood"
extract_search_tokens(x3)

# $exclude
# [1] "lymphatic"
# 
# $include
# [1] "blood"
# 
# $unknown
# [1] "pimple"
```

Comment: thanks, although I didn't state it in my question, I want "+lymphatic system -blood" to work too, so separating on spaces won't work - but I appreciate the great response, very useful.

Comment: @smackenzie So what's your expected output for "+lymphatic system -blood"? With my code "system" is thrown to the "unknown" chunk like case 3. Do you want to merge it with "+lymphatic"?

Comment: Yes, kymphatic system would be a required term (so an include token of two words) in the search results.  This is why my algorithm to extract tokens moves forward through the string rather than using regex (couldn't work it out).

Comment: I actually solved the original question by returning a list not a vector, my extraction of tokens works, albeit a bit long code wise.  My question as an R newbie was more why my vecotr response was as it was.